# Ionic2 how to enable mapTypeControl in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am working on a mobile app built on top of ionic2 and it uses [Google Map](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) plugin.

I am able to get the map up and running just fine how ever I am struggling with how to enable the control for `mapTypeControl`.

This is how I am trying to set the options

```
map.setOptions({
    'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'zoom': true
    },
    'camera': {
        'target': ionic,
        'zoom': 18,
    },
    'styles':{
        'mapTypeControl': true,
        'MapStyleOptions': {
            'style': 'DROPDOWN_MENU'
        }
    },
    'mapTypeIds': ['MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN', 'MAP_TYPE_HYBRID']
});
```

[image]

As you will notice that the map appears but the control is missing.

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options?hl=es-419) of google map it seems pretty straight forward

```
          mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
          }
```

What I am struggling with is how to covert that code into the style that is acceptable by the plugin? Any help will be appreciated.